# How to set unit for diff()?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several different variables (e.g. location, species, date & time). I'm trying to find the difference between two timestamps within the same column, according to location and species.

What my data frame looks like:

```
dat <- data.frame(
location = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
ID = c("x","y","x","x","x","y","y","x","x"),
datetime = c("2019-09-02 11:33:00","2019-09-03 10:00:00","2019-08-23 14:22:34","2019-09-12 12:18:00","2019-09-15 09:40:00","2019-09-15 09:40:00","2019-09-15 10:05:00","2019-08-23 13:58:18","2019-09-16 09:34:00"))
```

I grouped my data frame by location and ID and calculated the time difference with this:

```
Data1 <- Data %>% group_by(location, ID) 
Data2<-mutate(Data1,diff:=c(1000, diff(datetime)))
```

This successfully gives me the time difference, but for some reason they're randomly in different units (seconds, minutes, hours). I tried this instead:

```
Data2<-mutate(Data1,diff:=c(1000, diff(datetime, units="mins")))
```

but the output doesn't change. Is there a way to set the units, and if not is there an alternative way to get the time difference in a data frame sorted by specific variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `difftime`

```
library(dplyr)
Data1 %>%
  mutate(diff  = difftime(datetime, lag(datetime,
      default = first(datetime)), unit = 'mins'))
```